# finding all numbers less than x in a BST

Tags: algorithm

how would i do this? I am not sure when I would stop the bst search.

Comment: i am just wondering how would i modify the bst search to get the number of elements less than x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each node of your tree has a field `numLeft` that tells you how many nodes there are in its left subtree (counting itself too), then you can do this in `O(log N)`

Just keep adding `numLeft` to a global result variable for each node whose value is less than `x`:

```
countLessThan(int x, node T)
    if T = null
        return
    if T.value >= x
        countLessThan(x, T.left) // T.left contains only numbers < T.value and T.right only numbers > T.value
    else
        globalResult += T.numLeft
        countLessThan(x, T.right)
```

This will only count the numbers. If you want to print them, you need to write a depth first traversal that will print a subtree given as parameter. You can find plenty of those online, so I won't post that.

Answer (score 1):

If you need list of number you'll need to traverse tree anyway. For BST you can do traversing from lowest to highest.
But if you need subtree which represents lowest numbers:

```
def splitLowerTree(x, node):
  if node is None: return None
  elif node.value == x: return node.left
  elif node.value < x:
      if node.right is None: return node
      else: return Node(node.value, left = node.left, right = splitLowerTree(x, node.right))
  else: return splitLowerTree(x, node.left)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to get the count with the recursive way.

```
const lessThan = (n, v) => {
  if (!n) return 0  
    
  if (v > n.value) {
    return lessThan(n.left, v) + 1 
      + lessThan(n.right, v)
  } else {
    return lessThan(n.left, v)
  }
}
```

For an existing tree of `[5,11,-1,3,4,2]`, asking how many less than `8` will be `5`. Check out the demo below.

```js
const Node = (value, left = null, right = null) => ({ 
    value, left, right
})

// insert a value
const push = (node, v) => {
    let n = node
    let p = null
    
    while (n) {
        if (v < n.value) { 
            p = n
            n = n.left 
        } else {
            p = n
            n = n.right
        }
    }
    
    const added = Node(v)
    if (v < p.value) {
        p.left = added
    } else {
        p.right = added
    }   
}

// how many less than a value
const lessThan = (n, v) => {
    if (!n) return 0    
    
    if (v > n.value) {
        return lessThan(n.left, v) + 1 
            + lessThan(n.right, v)
    } else {
        return lessThan(n.left, v)
    }
}

const root = Node(2)
push(root, 4)
push(root, 3)
push(root, -1)
push(root, 11)
push(root, 5)
console.log(lessThan(root, 8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for or not, but binary search tree algorithms are classic and the internet is full of them. http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Lookup - should at least get you going in the right direction (you would want to modify the 'found' condition and return a 'collection' instead of a bool).