# given a sorted array of numbers, how do i find the size of numbers less than x

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [finding all numbers less than x in a BST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126703/finding-all-numbers-less-than-x-in-a-bst)

How would I modify a binary search to find the number of numbers in a sorted array that are less than a certain number?

Comment: Does BST stand for binary search tree in this context?

Comment: Your title says "sorted array", but you ask about a BST in your question? Is this homework?

Comment: Didn't you ask the exact same thing earlier today? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126703/finding-all-numbers-less-than-x-in-a-bst

Comment: What I asked before was a BST, now it's just an array of sorted numbers.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. The last question was about finding items in a binary search tree. This question is about finding items in a sorted array. The questions and answers are completely different and these should not be merged! Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an already sorted array of numbers simply find the insertion point for your item in the sorted array usng a [binary search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). The index of the insertion point gives you the number of elements that are less than your target number.

In your comments you raised two good questions:

- What if the number is not in the list?

To handle this you keep searching until you find the point where the number should be if it were present, that is the index where the current element is greater than x and the previous element is less than x.

- What if there are duplicates?

To handle this, instead of stopping when you first find an element, continue searching until you lower bound and upper bound meet. If you hit a value that is equal to x treat it in the same way as if you found a number that was too high and continue bisecting.

Comment: may be he meant sorting using "binary-search tree" method.

Comment: The problem is that number might not be inside the array, so I don't know when you would terminate the search. Even if it is a match we still maybe need to look at the left or right because there could be duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Return all numbers less than the index of the value returned by the binary search.

Answer (score 0):

Find number and check index.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is specifically an array of numbers and not just comparable objects, you might want to look at [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search).  If the numbers are uniformly distributed, it can find the index in O(log log n) time instead of O(log n).

Answer (score -1):

Binary search for the largest number lower than your given number. Once you have its position, that position also directly relates to the count you're interested in.

This pseudocode should get you on the right track, but I haven't tested it. `k` = given number

```
while left < right
    mid = (left + right) / 2
    if arr[mid] >= k // too big, not interested
        right = mid;
    else             // maybe too small, try bigger values
        left = mid + 1

 right - 1 or left - 1 (they're equal) is the position you're after.
```

For example: `8 11 13 20 50`, `k = 19`

```
left = 1, right = 5
mid = 3
arr[3] = 13 < 19 => left = 4

left = 4, right = 5
mid = 4
arr[4] = 20 >= 19 => right = 4

left >= right => left - 1 = 4 - 1 = 3 is the position you're after
```